# What is the use of scripting and how can i make the two language communicate

Tags: java, scripting

[Sorry for my terrible grammar and syntax but i'm italian]
i know thath there are a lot of scripting languages like lua, python, javascript..
i usually program in java but i still don't understand how to make the scripts comunicate to the main program

```
ScriptEngine js = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("js");
```

Then i read a file that contains the script and i insert it in *res* variable

```
try {
    js.eval(res);
} catch (ScriptException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I run the code and stop. but as so i can only make the script printing text on the console.
At the end my question is: "why is a script usefull?" what i can do with a script that i can't without? is it simpler to do certain things?"

Comment: your script can `return`values

Comment: so at the end of the script i can write _return x_ and
   Object value = js.eval(res);
will return me the value?

Comment: I used Scripting to evaluate functions the user typed in. Object result = js.eval("3*sin(2.5)/17") as an example.

Comment: so for example i can create a game that generates level writed in javascript or lua or something else by creating an object with all the info that te game needs and return it from the script?

Comment: @Ralf Renz so i can create a game that generates level writed in javascript or lua or something else by creating an object with all the info that te game needs and return it from the script? and how can i return it? i just write at the end of the script the name of the variable that i want to return or i use a keyword?

Comment: Evaluating functions is at the moment the only use case I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i came up with this script in javascript:

```
load("lib.js");

imgSize = 60;

setSound("bounce.wav");
rndSound(["bounce.wav", "gigi.wav"]);
rndSoundDisable(3, 1);
rndImg(1920 - imgSize * 2, 1080 - imgSize * 2, "logo.png");
addImg(0, 0, "bg.png");
rndImg(1920 - imgSize * 2, 1080 - imgSize * 2, "blub.png");

data;
```

you can imagine what the function do. and this is the java code:

```
ScriptEngine INTERPRETER = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("js")
String scriptText = "";
FileReader fr = null;
BufferedReader br = null;
try {
    fr = new FileReader(new File(script));
    br = new BufferedReader(fr);

    String currentLine;
    while((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null)
        scriptText += currentLine;

} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("Script " + script + " not found");          
}
ScriptObjectMirror obj = null;

try {
    obj = (ScriptObjectMirror) INTERPRETER.eval(scriptText);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return obj.to(String[].class);
```

that putted in a function return the String[] containing the value of data from js